# Can two applications that run in the same process have different STATIC object values?

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I created two Android applications that share the same user Id (sharedUserId) as well as the same process.
In the first app, on startup, I set a static int variable to 1 (it's default is 0).
In the second app, I load (using reflection) the same class from the other app and read the static int variable. I read 0.

Since both applications run on the same process, I would expect them to share the same static values, no?
Can anyone tell me what the mechanism underneath does?
(are they using, maybe, different apk/dex loaders and that causes this behavior?)

Comment: are you sure they are actually running in the same process?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Using reflection in an attempt to access static variables in another app sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to exchange data between my two apps, and this seems like a better idea than using a content provider or using intents (both of these methods are good, but they take up two many resources especially when it comes to Bitmaps).  <br/> I don't understand why my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is this....
It has to do with class loaders is Java and not processes or applications.

Java language: A class is identified by its fully qualified name
Java Virtual Machine: A class object is identified by its fully qualified name and defining class loader

Instances of classes loaded by the same classloader will definitely see the same static variables. A classloader usually delegates to its parent classloader. If the parent has already loaded the class it will not load it again. This standard behavior can be changed by writing your own class loader. The result is that a hierarchy of classloaders will only load a class once and therefore allocate static variables and run static blocks once.
     However if you have multiple hierarchies of classloaders you can load the same class multiple times and have static members allocated multiple times. Two class objects defined by different class loaders are different types even if they are generated from the same class file. Instances of classes loaded by the same classloader see the same static variables. A good reference is chapter 6 of Java Reflection in Action by Forman and Forman.

Thank you for Chris Matawa for giving me the answer on this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/8-b5T1zYr-8

Answer (score 0):

> **but they take up two many resources especially when it comes to *Bitmaps***

Using a static variable to share a bitmap between different application (or even between different activities from the same application) would be a bad idea in term of memory leak; see http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/ for an example.

Instead of economising resources, using static variables to share data and resources between activities and applications makes things worse because not only all this stuff will remain in memory forever (or at least for a long time and this, even when you don't need them anymore) but even more, these static things can bring along with them a lot of other things because of hidden and unknown references.

This if why you should pass datas using either Intents, SharedPreferences or a database and leave to each activity the care of loading what it needs in term of resources.

Some big resource who takes time to load can sometimes be shared between different activities but then, you need to be extra careful with that used if you don't want to leak away a lot of memory; which is something that's always precious on any mobile.